You had one job, tile man!
The answer is one word (7 letters)

Hints

 focus on the title: If you google it, what do you notice?


 Look at the tags, there is a jigsaw-puzzle..


 How many times is it possible to use that tag?


Since this is a [tag:jigsaw-puzzle], we need to match up the tiles somehow…

@TheEmptyStringPhotographer, exactly. But how many times is that possible? ;)

The tiles

 can be matched up in seven different ways: the starting configuration has them matched up by the corners, in brown. You can also arrange them so that the red cells in adjacent edges match; then you can do this again for orange, and yellow, and so on.

Doing this,

 the arrows form patterns in each configuration... except each has an odd arrow out. The title hints at this, referring to memes of this form:


 (Diagrams of the seven layouts and their "mislaid tiles" are shown in tToE's answer.)

We can get an answer by

 taking each of the mislaid tiles, and looking at which four numbers of that color are on the tile. (So for the starting configuration's mislaid tile, we look at the four brown numbers; for the next, we look at the four red numbers on that tile, and so on.)

 Adding up these four numbers gives us a result from 1 to 26, which we can convert to a letter:

 so the answer is SIXFOLD.


the starting configuration has them matched up by the corners, in brown. How is that?

@M.Riyan Take a look at the center of the image in the original puzzle: four tiles touch there, and all four have a 7 in that corner. The same goes for every other place where four tiles touch - their corners agree. (And on the edges of the picture, where only 2 tiles touch, the corners agree there too.)

I guess the word is:

 elitism

Here is my try:

 







Supp:

 I just picked out the seven 'odd' tiles, and consider the numbers on the corners of each tile.
 


Adding more explanation would make this answer more understandable.

As OP, I understand the images, and those are correct. However I have no idea how you came to the final answer. And that final word is unfortunately not correct.

@Lezzup I tried 'Qat' tool to help me find the possibly correct words (using the numbers on the corners......), but I only find this word (〒︿〒)....

@tToE, why every time the corner numbers, why not using the numbers of the colors you used to tile everything? ;)
